# SMS control using old Sony Ericsson and ATmega8

Tags: avr

I'm a student and having a project that using an ATmega8-16PU to control simple alarm (just LED and Buzzer) with SMS (using a Sony Ericsson K508i as a GSM module). [Refer to this link](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,52794.0.html)

I have questions :

1. Should i use internal 8Mhz or an extra external 8Mhz crystal for 9600 Baud Rate ? I had read before that better not to use internal clock.
2. [It says](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,52794.0.html) to use a phone-RS232 cable (cut off the plug and connect the wires), but can i just [directly](http://www.serasidis.gr/circuits/smscontrol/smscontroller.htm) connect the phone Tx Rx pins to ATmega8 Rx Tx pins ?

Please Help, I'm a software engineering student and have minimal hardware knowledge. This is my first time working with microcontroller.

Comment: I've never had a problem with internal oscillator for serial comms, but [some people have](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61195/atmega168-uart-8-data-bits-no-parity-1-stop-bit). It appears that connecting directly is save: both types of signal are 5V: using the cable might be physically easier.

Comment: Thank you @angelatlarge for the comment. I'm ready to setting my ATmega8 to using internal oscillator at 8Mhz. But as i know so far, you can only setting it just one time, right ? or if using internal is not working for the serial comms, can i set it again using an external one ? --- Yes, some said it save to working at 5V, but the phone working at [3V](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,52794.0.html), i just confused with others that use max232.

Comment: Your second link said 5v, so if that's right you are OK. If it is 3V you will need serial level shifter. Yes, try internal first, then change to exteral: you tell the ATmega which one to use by setting [fuse values](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/)

Comment: @angelatlarge Thanks for your time. I don't know anything about serial level shifter, do you have any link that explain it simply ? or how to build one ? or maybe i can just use [2k Ohm resistor] (http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,52794.0.html) ?

Comment: See [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43498/how-can-i-use-a-12-v-input-on-a-digital-arduino-pin/60436#60436). Or just buy (or get samples of) the [MAX3223](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3221-MAX3243.pdf)

Comment: To my knowledge AVR fuses can be reprogrammed many times. Only few combinations may brick your device (eg. too low frequency or external clock) or lock the fuse bits. `fuses` is a confusing term as it might imply write-once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some answers collected from the comments above:

- On the internal vs. external oscillator: YMMV. I've never had problems with the internal oscillator, but [some people have had issues with it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61195/atmega168-uart-8-data-bits-no-parity-1-stop-bit).  You switch the setting for using internal oscillator versus external crystal resonator by programming the chip's [fuses](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/)
- Whether you can connect the phone directly to your ATmega 8 depends on whether both are running on the same Vcc. ATmega8L can run on as little as 2.7V, whereas ATmega8 (no L) needs at least 4.5V.  I don't know what the phone runs at, your [second link](http://www.serasidis.gr/circuits/smscontrol/smscontroller.htm) seems to suggest 5V.
- If the voltage is not the same you will need to shift *at least* the phone's RX/ATmegas TX line down to the level that will not blow the phone.  See [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43498/how-can-i-use-a-12-v-input-on-a-digital-arduino-pin/60436) for some strategies.  The phone's TX/ATmega's RX line should be fine: the phone's 3V high should register correctly as high on the ATmega.  I have usually used the diode+resistor strategy for shifting a single line to 3V3 on two-wire interfaces.  But if you want a chip for this you can use the [MAX3223](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3221-MAX3243.pdf).